# Not getting values of fields of types Droplist and TreeList from Lucene index

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I am using Sitecore 7.2. I created a custom Lucene index.

While I am able to get the values of fields of type `Single-line Text`, `Rich Text` & `DateTime`, I am not getting the values of fields of types such as `Droplist` and `TreeList`.

I have tried changing the indexType of these fields to "UNTOKENISED" but still continue to get this issue. I also checked my index using Luke and observed that only the Title, Summary and Body fields are part of the index.

Below is the portion of my index configuration where I've defined my fields. `products` and `type` are `Treelist` and `Droplist` fields respectively.

```
<fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
  <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
    <field fieldName="title" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    </field>
    <field fieldName="summary" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    </field>
    <field fieldName="body" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    </field>
    <field fieldName="datemodified" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    </field>
    <field fieldName="products" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    </field>
    <fieldType fieldName="type" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"
      settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
  </fieldNames>
</fieldMap>
```

The class I am using to fetch values from the index is as below:

```
public class DownloadResult : SearchResultItem
    {
        [IndexField("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [IndexField("summary")]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        [IndexField("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [IndexField("body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }

        [IndexField("datemodified")]
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

        [indexfield("products")]
        public string products { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: What does your class you are using for Search look like?

Comment: When you look at the field in Luke, does it have value?

Comment: @dnstommy Yes it does. When I change the type to Single-Line Text and rebuild index, the values are returned.

Comment: @RichardSeal Please see my edit

Comment: @RichardSeal I have checked this index using Luke. These fields are not included in the index itself.

Answer (score 0):

please check your search's default configuration file for fieldtypes "DropList" and "TreeList". If its not added please add it: It will look something like this:

```
<fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldTypes">
…
<fieldType name="droplist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
<fieldType name="treelist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
…
</fieldTypes>
```

Comment: My Default Lucene index configuration already has the fieldtypes for DropList and TreeList

Answer (score 0):

In the file **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config**

you need to have next fieldReaders for indexing droplist,treelist,etc.
These are default configuration in Sitecore:

```
         <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|treelistex|tree list"  fieldNameFormat="{0}" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
         <fieldReader fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist"                     fieldNameFormat="{0}" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
         <fieldReader fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list"             fieldNameFormat="{0}" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NameValueListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
         <fieldReader fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree"            fieldNameFormat="{0}" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.LookupFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
```

please check if you have these configurations and if you reference this config file into your custom index file.

Comment: Yes I do have these configurations in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your fields like this, this always works for me:

```cs
 [IndexField("products")]
 public IEnumerable<ID> Products { get; set; }

 [IndexField("type")]
 public IEnumerable<ID> Type { get; set; }
```

You could also try adjusting the storage type settings in the `AddFieldByFieldTypeName` settings

```
 <fieldType fieldTypeName="droptree" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

Comment: I have checked my index using Luke and observed that only the Title, Summary and Body fields are part of the index. Therefore it's not a problem with the model. The products and type fields are not added to the index itself.

Comment: Ok, double check that it is in the index by looking at the top terms rather than the search screen. If not I've also suggested above changing the `storageType` to yes in the `AddFieldByFieldTypeName` settings as well as the `AddFieldByFieldName` settings. If this doesn't help then there's something customer causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use computed index fields to get such fields (Treelist and Droplist) indexed.
Reference for HowTo : [How to Add Computed Index](http://reasoncodeexample.com/2014/04/01/computed-index-fields-sitecore-7-content-search/)

Answer (score 0):

(Not able to comment on Sairaj's answer)

While `indexAllFields` is a *solution* it is not ideal.  The real problem I assume (since it happened to us) is that you are trying to index a field in which it's value is pulled from standard values.  While viewing the item in Content Editor, it looks to have a value, but per Lucene (don't ask my why) it does not have a value.

Apparently Lucene does not read a fields value from standard values unless you tell it to `indexAllFields`.  While a custom field could also be used to solve this problem, I feel like this is either A) a bug in Sitecore or B) a configuration option that no one has been able to track down.

(Edit)

We noticed this on 8.1

Answer (score -1):

After trying out all the different suggestions and hitting a blank, I changed the value of `indexAllFields` to true in the configuration. That solved it.